# Having trouble concatenating two strings in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to concatenate two strings in TypeScript like this:

```
let string1 = new String("IdNumber: " + this.IdNumber);
let string2 = new String(this.notes);
this.notes = string1.concat(string2.toString());
```

The output I see for this.notes on line 3 is missing the original text from this.notes in string2.
This is what I see in devTools for this.notes on line 3 when debugging:

```
"IdNumber: 524242

"
```

when hovering over this.notes on line 2 in devTools it looks like this:

```
"testing

 testing 2

 testing 3"
```

I was hoping that this.notes on line 3 would look like this:

```
"IdNumber: 524242

 testing

 testing 2

 testing 3"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: String objects in JavaScript are *very rarely* useful. They are not the same as string primitive values.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now the `this` context is missing so it's hard to know what's going on.  I concur that `new String(...)` is almost certainly not what you want to do; you could use just `String(...)` instead.  But without being able to reproduce the issue, this is all just guesswork.

Comment: It might help if you could explain what you're trying to get that `"IdNumber: " + this.IdNumber + this.notes` wouldn't give you.

Comment: This code may not be good but I just realized that I made a mistake and was setting this.notes in a separate location that was overwriting what was being set here. It was still very helpful to see how to use the template literals instead of String objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a more ergonomic (if not idiomatic) approach would be using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), for example:

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOMC8MDeAUDDAJIAmAcgK4oBGcATgFwwCsATACzccA0xGGBBQ4EVgHJR0AJZgA5gB0wy6VDnyYHZarHqFMAMwSBJamnJJRMABQBKAoJJQAFjIgA6YdNwwABhQ09EysACT4ru4egbQMjAC+OmDhkZ7eYvF+ANyC8QLxOYSgkCBYHhgg8jaIqJhwXiJidlkwAPStMABEahpJPQbaKmD9moadhDXoZeaWovY5xRCl9RVVk3UN0s1tHZ0xwSzsvDx9er1DI1qnsgZjhEA)

```js
const example = {
  IdNumber: 524242,
  notes: 'testing\n\ntesting 2\n\ntesting 3',
  update () {
    this.notes = `IdNumber: ${this.IdNumber}\n\n${this.notes}`;
  },
};

console.log(example.notes); // "testing\n\ntesting 2\n\ntesting 3"
example.update();
console.log(example.notes); // "IdNumber: 524242\n\ntesting\n\ntesting 2\n\ntesting 3"
```

Answer (score 2):

For string concatenation it is recommended* to use Template Literals

```
let string1 = `IdNumber: ${this.IdNumber}`;
let string2 = `${this.notes}`;
this.notes = `${string1}${string2}`
```

* https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/prefer-template